# elasticsearch scripting with custom field name

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting

Basically I want to do a custom script sorting based on some fields. They fields may vary according to different criteria. Before we have the dynamic scripting enabled so it was fine because I can change the keyword at my side. However now only scripting by file is allowed. 
This is my query:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
       ...
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "file": "myFile",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

The file looks like:

```
doc["keyword1"].value > 5 ? 5 : doc["keyword1"].value
```

Though I can build different queries(using different files there) based on the keyword name. I'm wondering if we can actually pass the keyword as a parameter so that there is no need to store multiple files under the scripts/ folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Your script file should look like this:

```
doc[some_param].value > 5 ? 5 : doc[some_param].value
```

And your query like this:

```
  "functions": [
    {
      "script_score": {
        "file": "test",
        "params": {
          "some_param": "keyword1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```